# Неправильно работает таймер в Flask

Tags: python, flask

Хочу чтобы метод запускался каждые 5 сек. В логах почему то 3 сек, 2 сек.. Как ровно отмерить время?

```
def checker_thread():
    while True:
        print(time.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = threading.Thread(target=checker_thread)
    x.start()

    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня 5 секунд, всё ок https://repl.it/repls/OtherMiserableInternet

Comment: Возможно, это поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds